# Send Bulk emails without getting black listed

Tags: email, spam-prevention

I want to send news letters to my clients and also to public visitors ( nearly 50,000 members ) without getting blacklisted , I tried amazon ses , mail chimp , sendy kind of tools but i dont want to register my domain because it might get black listed or spammed

Comment: If it looks like Shoulder of Pork and haM, ... it probably is.

Comment: The whole point of properly sending out mass mail is doing it from your real domain. How else would services like MailChimp exist if that concept didn't work?

Answer (score 2):

Hiding yourself will increase the possiblity to be blacklisted. Sending from a valid domain (i.e., reverse DNS lookup will work) with an SPF record will help **not** to be considered as spam.